# How to pass keys in Azure gateway application

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-gateway

I have configured app services as backend pool in application gateway and want to pass key to access that app services(function) through application gateway as the authorization level for that app service is not anonymous.

What are the steps to do this?

Comment: please add the related codes.